# Change service config parameters at runtime

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using mailgun to send mails thought Laravel 5.2. It configured on config/services.php like that:

```
    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('mailgun_domain','mydomain.com'),
        'secret' => env('mailgin_secret','my-secret-key-132152345423')
    ],
```

But, I need change that settings in run time, before call Mail::send, to use the correct service parameters. It must be changed many times during runtime.

I **cannot configure it by .env file**, because all data will be get from database, where the user setups the domain and secret.

Comment: Do you know what the settings will be or are they always changing/dynamically pulled from another source?

Comment: The code must change the "mailgun" domain and secret before send a mail. That data will be on database. I need change it many times during a execution.

Comment: The solution proposed by @alexey-mezenin work well for the first change, after that, it doesn't change anymore.. just the first value remains.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you need to do. It's a pretty unique scenario. Let me think about it.

Comment: When sending mails on behalf of your user, you should never user their credentials as global settings!!! What if the app dispatches other mails during the same request, e.g. notify the admin about an event… @JaredEitnier s answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can set config values dynamically at runtime with [`config()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-config) helper:

```
config(['services.mailgun' => $arrayWithNewSettings]);
```

Comment: Thanks @alexey-mezenin, when I set it in runtime at first time, it work well. But when I change it, if I got the config value, it's ok, but when Mail use it, just the first value are there.. just the first config stay there. I need force service to reload config...

Comment: @astroanu before downvoting you could actually read the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

Comment: The question asks about "changing" config value at run time, not substituting if not exists. To set a config value use Config::set($key, $value). your solution is the equalant of Config::get('services.mailgun', $arrayWithNewSettings);

Comment: @astroanu, `Config::set($key, $value)` is the same as `config(['services.mailgun' => $arrayWithNewSettings]);`. To get the value you're using `config('services.mailgun');`. Read the documentation again.

Comment: i guess it does then. didn't see.

Answer (score 1):

you can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68210051/14308480) it's working on Laravel 8. You need to change some piece of code as I mentioned below.

```
config(
    [
        'mail.driver' => 'mailgun',
        'services.mailgun.domain' => 'your domain.com',
        'services.mailgun.secret' => 'your mail gun secrets'
    ]
);
(new Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider(app()))->register();
```

Comment: `config()` params are `array|null|string $key mixed` Not needs 3 instances of `config()`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30237761/1133306) you'll be on the right track.

`\Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager.php` has a method `createMailgunDriver()` which is pulling services from a hard location that is not changeable by default.

You'll need to write your own service provider, extend the `MailServiceProvider` and roll your own transport so that you can pull your settings from the db like you want to.

Comment: Checking now.. I'm not right if it will work and how to implement it.. :(

Comment: @TiagoGouvêa what issue you are facing in implementing the above solution ?

Comment: @TiagoGouvêa I checked the answer, what you can do is check the answer , try to implement it by creating each file and let me know the step u r stuck in

Comment: I decided to take another solution.... "less glamorous" but efficient, without use the services. Thanks for all replies!