# How to set session cookie for multiple domains in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies

My Laravel application can be accessed using 2 different domain names `www.4evergaming.com` and `www.best4games.com` *(these are not my actual domains, just an example)*

Here is how my routes file looks like

```
Route::pattern('domain', '(www.4evergaming.com|www.best4games.com)');
Route::domain('{domain}')->group(function ()
{
    // Routes here...
})
```

But in my `config/session.php` I can only have one domain...

```
'domain' => '.4evergaming.com',
```

I need to set session cookies for both domains but how can I do this? Or is there a way to copy the sessions across domains somehow?

Comment: Use what https://stackoverflow.com/a/38874160/1427878 suggests to set the correct value at runtime? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-config The info which host name was actually used to access your project, you’ll find in `$_SERVER`.

Comment: I came across this exact issue today. This code allow you to set your cookies domain according to the requested one. Im more curious about how you solved (if you felt it was an issue), the problem of cookies sharing between both domains ? For example, if you store a login cookie on domain A, how do you keep this cookie when switching to domain B ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing config at runtime like this.

```
Route::pattern('domain', '(www.4evergaming.com|www.best4games.com)');
Route::domain('{domain}')->group(function ()
{
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www.best4games.com') !== false) {
        config([ 'session.domain' => 'www.best4games.com' ]);
    }
})
```