# SSH into dynamic remote server and run a command - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ssh, laravel-5.8

I'm using L 5.8 and I have a form with 3 inputs

[image]

Right now, I can SSH into a specific server with this package `laravelcollective/remote": "~5.8`. I required to ***pre*** *configured* IP, UN, PW in the `config/remote.php` like so :

```
'connections' => [
    'production' => [
        'host'      => '1.1.1.1',
        'username'  => 'code',
        'password'  => '8888',
        'key'       => '',
        'keytext'   => '',
        'keyphrase' => '',
        'agent'     => '',
        'timeout'   => 10,
    ],
],
```

Then, I can easily run any command(s) or even chain them

```
$commands = ['cd /home/code && ./runMe.sh'];
SSH::run($commands, function($line)
{
    echo $line.PHP_EOL;
});
```

**Result**

My portal will connect to that server and run that command successfully, and I've verified it.

---

## Now

I need to read it from form inputs. Is it possible to use the same plugin and dynamically setting that file `remote.php` ?

***or***

Should I start looking into something else because this is a dead end ?

Please advise,

Comment: Is `remote.php` located at `config/remote.php`? Edit: just saw your update, it is  You can use the `config(['remote.connections.production.host' => $request->input('host')])` on the fly, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38874160/3965631 (or `username`, `ip`, `password`, etc)

Comment: We can do that ? That will be cool if I can just do that. I usually have to my Input::all() or Request::all() in my controller file, but never tried the config file. Do you get my point ?

Comment: If this code is being called from a Controller, or somewhere where the `$request` or `request()` variable/helper is available, you can do that to modify `config/remote.php` on the fly. I.e. you can override config settings like that, but I don't think you can create new ones/persist them to the file, etc etc. Sidenote, I haven't use this plugin, so I could be wrong, but at a glance that _should_ be ok?

Comment: See https://github.com/LaravelCollective/remote/issues/41

Comment: According to [the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/ssh), `SSH` was last available in 4.2, how are you using it in 5.8?

Comment: @php_nub_qq by requiring the `laravelcollective/remote` composer package as he wrote?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `config()` helper here:

example config:

```php
config([
'remote.connections.production.host' => $request->input('hostname'),
'remote.connections.production.username' => $request->input('username'),
'remote.connections.production.password' => $request->input('password')
]);
```

then call:

```
$commands = ['cd /home/code && ./runMe.sh'];
SSH::run($commands, function($line)
{
    echo $line.PHP_EOL;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This example require the package `php-ssh2`, and provide many ways to retrieve the remote shell STDOUT as a stream. It's also great to control the current machine shell and get responses.

```
sudo apt install php-ssh2
```

Or by version:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-ssh2
```

Example usage of [`ssh2_exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php) and [`ssh2_fetch_stream()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-fetch-stream.php):

```
<?php
$ssh = ssh2_connect('192.162.68.212', 22); // Remote address
ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'root', 'XQA8DCamdEm'); // Credentials
$shell = ssh2_shell($ssh, 'xterm'); // Choose remote shell
$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'cd /home/code && ./runMe.sh'); // Remote command
stream_set_blocking($stream, true); // Wait for multiline output, till EOF
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO); // SSH2_STREAM_STDERR
echo stream_get_contents($stream_out); // Print in real-time
```

It is possible to retrieve only the errors, this is great for monitoring only without parsing the whole output, by using the flag `SSH2_STREAM_STDERR`.

To write *strings* only to `STDERR` from *the remote* PHP, we can use:

```
fwrite(STDERR, "Some logs, from machine (...)\n");
```

Or we can pipe the errors directly in the remote shell command:

`cd /home/code && ./runMe.sh 2>`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php